# Plotting cones from data read from a file

Tags: plotting, graphics, data

I would like to plot cones centered at specific points in a lattice and with different orientations and colors that depend on them. For this, I have the data in an external file with 11 columns: 
1) the first 5th columns are not relevant.
2) column c6 has the theta spherical angle.
3) columns c7,c8 are the x and y components of my vectors.
4) columns c9,c10,c11 are the x,y,z coordinates of the lattice nodes.

To plot the cones I use the Cone[{x0,y0,z0},{xf,yf,zf},r] commmand that needs the coordinates of the start and end of the Cone[{x0,y0,z0},{xf,yf,zf},r] to be drawn. So, my idea was setting the coordinates as read from the different columns as:

```
 x0=c9-cos(phi)*sin(c6), y0=c10-sin(phi)*sin(c6), z0=c11-sin(c6)
 xf=c9+cos(phi)*sin(c6), yf=c10+sin(phi)*sin(c6), zf=c11+sin(c6)
```

where phi=ArcTan[c7,c8].
I have used the following code to implement this. But it is obvious that it does not work. Cones are plotted where they should but neither orientation nor color are correct. Any idea on how to modify Posi and Posf so as to add or substract the proper quantities? Any idea on how to modify the Hue?

```
data = Import["a.dat", "Table"];
CosTh = Cos[data[[;; , 6]]];
SinTh = Sin[data[[;; , 6]]];
CosPhi = Cos[ArcTan[data[[;; , 7]], data[[;; , 8]]]];
SinPhi = Sin[ArcTan[data[[;; , 7]], data[[;; , 8]]]];
Posi = data[[;; , 9 ;; 11]] - CosPhi;
Posf = data[[;; , 9 ;; 11]] + CosPhi;
Pos2 = Transpose[{Posi, Posf}];
Graphics3D[{Hue[CosTh], Cone[Pos2, 0.5]}]
```

Sample file (a.dat):

```
5 1 0 0   0    0.4003 -0.28 -0.27 50.00 50.00 13.00
2 1 0 0   0    1.8608  0.82 -0.49 47.00 42.00 14.00
2 1 0 0   0    1.3921 -0.30 -0.94 48.00 42.00 14.00
2 1 0 0   0    2.1094 -0.81 -0.29 49.00 42.00 14.00
9 1 0 0   0    1.2351  0.90 -0.27 50.00 42.00 14.00
9 1 0 0   0    1.1159 -0.62 -0.65 51.00 42.00 14.00
9 1 0 0   0    0.8004 -0.53  0.48 52.00 42.00 14.00
9 1 0 0   0    1.5252  0.41 -0.91 53.00 42.00 14.00
2 1 0 0   0    1.4176  0.81  0.57 46.00 43.00 14.00
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: A quick fix for the plotting problem: `Graphics3D@Transpose[{Hue/@CosTh, Cone[#, 0.5]&/@Pos2}]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix on the Hue problem. I am not completely sure about the notation with @ /@ and &/@ that you use. Could you pleass rewrite the expression without these symbols?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. Thank you for the advice:

```
data = Import["Example.nba", "Table"];
conespec = {Cos@#1, {Cos[ArcTan[#2, #3]]*Sin[#1], Sin[ArcTan[#2, #3]]*Sin[#1], Cos[#1]}, {#4, #5, #6}} & @@@ data[[All, 6 ;; 11]];
Graphics3D [{Hue[#1], Cone[{#3 - #2, #3 + #2}, 0.5]} & @@@ conespec]
```

Answer (score 2):

Barring some transcription errors (and also simplifying as some variables are unused in cone specification):

```
dat = ImportString["5 1 0 0   0    0.4003 -0.28 -0.27 50.00 50.00 13.00
   2 1 0 0   0    1.8608  0.82 -0.49 47.00 42.00 14.00
   2 1 0 0   0    1.3921 -0.30 -0.94 48.00 42.00 14.00
   2 1 0 0   0    2.1094 -0.81 -0.29 49.00 42.00 14.00
   9 1 0 0   0    1.2351  0.90 -0.27 50.00 42.00 14.00
   9 1 0 0   0    1.1159 -0.62 -0.65 51.00 42.00 14.00
   9 1 0 0   0    0.8004 -0.53  0.48 52.00 42.00 14.00
   9 1 0 0   0    1.5252  0.41 -0.91 53.00 42.00 14.00
   2 1 0 0   0    1.4176  0.81  0.57 46.00 43.00 14.00", "Table"];
conespec = {Cos@#1, Cos[ArcTan[#2, #3]], {#4, #5, #6}} & @@@ 
   dat[[All, 6 ;; 11]];
Graphics3D[{Hue[#1], Cone[{#3 - #2, #3 + #2}, 0.5]} & @@@ conespec]
```

[image]